OData expand query does not provide the expected flat table
I am trying to retrieve data from an OData source ;
in this source there are related data that I tried to expand :
https://myurl.com/odata/Reporting/v1/SupplierOfferRows?$expand=Item&$select=ID,Item/ID,Item/itemID
However this does not provide an expanded flat table :

Ideally I would like to retrieve a flat table with 3 columns in that case : ID, Item.ID and itemID. I do not understand why Item keep a compact format.
How should I proceed to do so?
Thank you for your help
